# power bi map show points within distance of selected point

Tags: powerbi

I have a list of projects and their coordinates which I am displaying on a map in Power BI. I also have a table on the page which lists the projects. When I click on a project in the map it filters the table and only shows the detail for that project.

What I would like to happen is when I click on a project on the map that it would show all the projects within a set distance from the selected project, for example all projects withing 100kms from the selected project.

how would I achieve this?

Comment: https://radacad.com/dynamic-distances-in-power-bi